# FLVPlayback false event complete triggered

Tags: actionscript-3, flvplayback

I am facing a problem with FLVPlayback complete event with AS3 publishing for FlashPlayer 11.1

The trouble is that after a few seconds of the video starts the complete event is triggered and the problem always occurs only after a few hours of playing a playlist of videos.

Some code here:

```
var my_player:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();

function makePlayer():void{
    my_player.scaleMode = "exactFit";
    my_player.x = video_x;
    my_player.y = video_y;
    my_player.width = video_width;
    my_player.height = video_height;

if(bBordi)
    my_player.mask = mask_mc;

    video.addChild(my_player);
    my_player.source = my_path + my_videos[nVideo].@URL;
    my_player.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completePlay);
    my_player.volume=video_volume;
}

function completePlay(e:fl.video.VideoEvent):void
{
    if(!my_player.stopped)
        return;

    trace("VIDEO ENDED: " + my_path + my_videos[nVideo].@URL)
    nVideo++;
    if(nVideo >= my_total)
        nVideo = 0;
    playPlayer();
}

function playPlayer():void{
    my_player.source=(my_path + my_videos[nVideo].@URL);
    my_player.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Publishing for FlashPlayer 11.8 resolve the problem.